# Get row counts from a multiple

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm executing a multi-delete `DELETE` query, like so:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM foo WHERE 1 = 1; DELETE FROM bar WHERE 1 = 1";
$statement = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
```

I'm aware that I can use `$statement->getRowCount()` if my query contained a single delete, but how can I *both* row counts?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way doing this in doctrine, but another solution could be:

```
$queries = [
    "DELETE FROM foo WHERE 1 = 1;",
    "DELETE FROM bar WHERE 1 = 1;"
];

$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$affectedRows = 0;

foreach($queries as $query)
{
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $affectedRows = $affectedRows + $statement->getRowCount();
}
```